# Special way of representing array in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, objective-c-literals

I have seen in many places over the net and even in apple documentation when an array is represented in the following format:

```
@[obj1,obj2]
```

For eg; In predicate programming guide there is a statement like this:

```
NSCompoundPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[greaterThanPredicate, lessThanPredicate]];
```

But when I write the same in code , i get an 'unexpected @ in program' (as expected) compiler error. Is this just a way of representing arrays or am i missing something?

Comment: Make sure you are using Xcode 4.4 or later and the latest LLVM compiler (not gcc).

Comment: @JoshCaswell I love your ability to find duplicates. But in this case, I think this one is off. The question indicates that he knows what the syntax does (creates an NSArray). The question is why isn't it working with `NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:`.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, @rmaddy. Let me explain my thinking: the first sentence of the accepted answer on the question I've linked specifies the required Xcode version. It's got approximately the same information that dasblinkenlight's here answer does.

Comment: I did a search for this and couldn't find any. Even the related questions couldn't help. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @JoshCaswell OK - I missed the Xcode version reference in the accepted answer. Keep up the stellar duplicate finding.

Comment: @Rakesh: There's generally no reproach intended with a duplicate proposal; it's just an attempt to keep related information all in one place instead of scattered across lots of differenct pages. Also, it's helpful to mention closely-related questions that you've already seen and found unhelpful (and why) in your question.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Yup. Didn't think otherwise. Although my search key words were not right. That was the problem. :)

Comment: Also relevant: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Whats to do when its been marked as duplicate by multiple people. Should I delete this? The solution is found useful by many though.

Comment: No, there's no need at all for you to delete it. Duplicates are fine to keep around (unless there's _dozens_).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a [relatively new syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html), it is available only with Xcode that includes clang 3.3 or newer.

This

```
@[greaterThanPredicate, lessThanPredicate]
```

is logically equivalent<sup>*</sup> to this:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:greaterThanPredicate, lessThanPredicate, nil]
```

You can always replace the new syntax with the old one without losing functionality.

**EDIT** (in response to a comment by [Nikolai Ruhe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104790/nikolai-ruhe))  Apple has a different version scheme than the open source version. The correct version numbers that introduced the feature are: Apple 4.0, clang 3.1.

---

<sup>*</sup> Under the hood the array initializer of the new syntax is transformed to a call of `arrayWithObjects:count:`. Thanks to [newacct](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86989/newacct) for the correction.

Comment: clang version numbers are a little confusing: Apple has a different version scheme than the open source version. The correct version numbers that introduced the feature are: Apple 4.0, clang 3.1

Comment: Note: (1) Xcode 4.4 is the earliest version which supports these Objective-C literals.  (2) If you build for iOS 5 or earlier, you should not use literals with mutable sets.

Comment: "is equivalent to this:" Not quite. It's equivalent to a call to `arrayWithObjects:count:`.

Comment: @newacct Thanks for the correction, I fixed the answer to reflect this.